# How can I load OSGi plugin with import-package "javax.servlet.annotation"

Tags: tomcat, servlets, osgi

I have a web application running in OSGi and is deployed to Tomcat. I have been registering my servlets by contributing to the extension point org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry in my plugin and adding the following packages to manifest.mf:

```
Import-Package: javax.servlet,
 javax.servlet.http
```

Things have been going fine so far.

Now, I would like to make one of my servlet async-supported. I tried to do this by adding the following annotation to my servlet class:

```
@WebServlet(name = "OrderServlet", urlPatterns = {"/order"}, asyncSupported = true)
public class OrderServlet extends HttpServlet {
...
}
```

This requires javax.servlet.annotation to be added to the manifest:

```
Import-Package: javax.servlet,
 javax.servlet.annotation,
 javax.servlet.http
```

When I re-deploy my WAR with this change, my plugin fails to load. OSGi console shows the following error when I try to manually start the bundle:

```
id      State       Bundle
5       INSTALLED   abc.asyncServlet_1.0.0
osgi> start 5
gogo: BundleException: The bundle "abc.asyncServlet_1.0.0 [5]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: javax.servlet.annotation; version="0.0.0"
osgi> diag 5
update@plugins/abc.asyncServlet_1.0.0.jar [5]
  Direct constraints which are unresolved:
    Missing imported package javax.servlet.annotation_0.0.0.
```

I am using Tomcat 7 and verified that the servlet-api.jar (version 3.0) in my tomcat/lib directory has the annotation package.

What can I be missing? Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: Which version of Equinox/Servlet bridge do you use? Older versions did not export all of the (newer) servlet packages (see [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371028)). And please avoid to [cross post](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1067797&goto=1699544&) questions.

Answer (score -1):

It's likely that the servlet-api.jar file is not being loaded by your osgi container. You may need to specify the jar in your config.ini file, or specify wherever you are configuring which bundles are available to your osgi container.

Answer (score -1):

Probably package `javax.servlet` is not being exported in your OSGi container by any bundle.
You can deploy the following OSGi ready bundle which exports this package:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
   <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```